# Constructing a function and it's variables

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to call the `age`, `name` and `height` together, from only 1 variable called `this.anh` from the function called `person`.
The way i wrote the list is wrong but what is the right notation? if there is multiple ways, please write them down. :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function person(age, name, height){
this.age = age;
this.name = name;
this.height = height;
this.anh = age, name, height;
}

var koolz = new person(20,"koolz",200);



document.write(koolz.anh)

</script>
```

Comment: What the expected result?
`"20, koolz, 200"` ?

Comment: yes! thats right! @EliasSoares

Answer (score 2):

You need to add literals where you want them and concatenate the dynamic values.

```js
function person(age, name, height){
   this.age = age;
   this.name = name;
   this.height = height;

   // If you want a literal comma and space to separate the values
   // then you need to concatenate them to the variables.
   this.anh = age + ", " +  name + ", " + height;

   // Or, if the data were in an array, like this:
   var arry = [this.age, this.name, this.height ];
   
   // You could concatenate them like this:
   var result = arry.join(", ");
   console.log(result);
}

var koolz = new person(20,"koolz",200);
document.write(koolz.anh)
```

Answer (score 1):

**ES5**

```
this.anh = age + ', ' + name + ', ' + height;
```

**ES6** ([template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

```
this.anh = `${age}, ${name}, ${height}`;
```

And instead of creating a new variable, [you can override the `toString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString):

```
function person(age, name, height) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height;
}

person.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.age + ', ' + this.name + ', ' + this.height;
}

var koolz = new person(20, 'koolz', 200);

koolz.toString() // "20, koolz, 200"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the variables to get your expected output.

```
this.anh = age + ', ' + name + ', ' + ', ' + height;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function person(age, name, height) {
  this.age = age;
  this.name = name;
  this.height = height;
  this.anh = function() {
    return this.age + ", " + this.name + ", " + this.height;
  };
  this.anh2 = age + ", " + name + ", " + height;
}

var koolz = new person(20, "koolz", 200);
console.log(koolz.anh())
console.log(koolz.anh2)

koolz.age = 25;
koolz.height = 210;

console.log("This has the updated values.")
console.log(koolz.anh())

console.log("Other way doesn't ever change")
console.log(koolz.anh2)
```

Since age, name and height are public properties you should use a function for "anh" so that it always returns an up to date value.  Otherwise "anh" could get out of sync with the other variables very easily.